# get image from SD card and set it to wallpaper

Tags: android, android-image

I made an application which contains a button .This button will take us to the phone's gallery where the user can choose any image and that image will shown in application below the button . Now i want a button which sets that image as the wallpaper,I need code for save button. 
here's the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT = 1;

Button b1,b2;
ImageView IV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    IV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri pick = data.getData();
        String[] images = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pick,images,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(images[0]));
        IV.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        cursor.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.button:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT);
    break;
        case R.id.save:
            break;

    }
    }
```

}

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: How to set the image as wallpaper??

Comment: Made many grammar fixes. Improved general meaning of the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understood your question correct me if i am wrong. You wanted to set the selected image as wallpaper.

```
WallpaperManager wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
   wManager.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Lastly you need this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER">
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! but the wallpaper is out of screen. I mean the standard android wallpaper is 640*480 so how i set image in this resolution ??

Comment: You should crop/resize your image accrodingly. Ask another question and explain your 'new' problem.

Comment: Yes! I have frames in drawable folder so i want to set these images in that frames before setting to wallpaper , can you please explain me how to do this?